# onEdit is not called on every cell edits

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a function named `onEditIsTriggered(e)` and I have registered it for the event "From Spreadsheet" => "On edit". I also have set myself up as receiving any errors through email immediately.

If I edit my cells on my Sheet normally at a normal pace, the event is called correctly and everything works perfectly. Although, if I edit my cells very quickly, it may skip 2 or 3 calls per 20 cells (on average) on a random basis for the same values as input.

I have tested this by adding this code at the very top of the `onEditIsTriggered` function: `Browser.msgBox(JSON.stringify(e));` and then, if I edit 2 cells very quickly (I have been able to reproduce it with 2 cells perfectly every times), the message box only opens once, then once I press Ok the script runs successfully for the first value, but there is nothing for the second value. If I change both cells with a small delay (~0.5 seconds more or less), then I get both prompts and both values are ran through the script.

Is this a known issue? or is there a rate limit that I haven't found any documentation on? is my approach not the right one? (It only happens when I edit 2 cells extremely quickly by using the down arrow and quickly entering data, which is a realistic use case in my situation)

My goal is to synchronise the same value across different associated cells. So when a change is detected on 1 of the values, then I apply the modifications to the other values. With this issue, it's impossible for me to design a script that would work with the "On edit" event and would have to revert to a scan every 5 minutes, but it creates risks of 2 associated cells being modified at the same time and my script not knowing which to choose.

Comment: Try using "Lock Service"  [https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock-service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock-service)  This isn't a quota issue.  When code is called from an event, instead of another independent instance of the function running, the previous instance of the function gets somehow affected.  Multiple independent instances of the function do not run when called in rapid succession.  Lock Service is designed to deal with situation like this.

Comment: I have added `var lock = LockService.getDocumentLock().tryLock(30000);` at the beginning of my function and `LockService.getDocumentLock().releaseLock();`. The script is simply not called at all for a few edits. If I look at the logs after editing 3 cells, I see only 2 calls to my `onEditIsTriggered` function.

Comment: If I slow down just a little, then it works alright (And thanks for the Lock function, it will indeed be useful if I get this script to work)

Comment: Are the edited ranges getting combined on sufficiently coincident edits?

Comment: No, I made the Browser.msgBox so it shows e.range.getA1Notation() and it's still only 1 cell. Ex. I will see "C3", then "C5", but not "C4".